# Google Feeling Lucky as search provider

Tags: search, internet-explorer-8, provider

Could you please help me to restore "Google Feeling Lucky" as a search provider in IE8?

Some time ago I found a website where you could add Feeling Lucky to search providers in IE8, but after a system reinstallation I cannot trace the page.

Answer (score 1):

I have finally found the website with different "addable" search providers. It works for both Firefox and IE. http://mycroft.mozdev.org/search-engines.html?category=12.